# Laravel unify multiple relations into one

Tags: php, laravel, relation

In my application there are three models: `User`, `Product` and `Retailer`. A user can optionally be associated with one `Retailer`.

Each `Product` belongs to one `User` and optionally one Retailer.

Users should then be able to access all `Product`s that belong to them, as well as all products that belong to the retailer they are associated with (if any).

Basically what this means is that I need to create two relations and somehow unify them.

```
public function products()
{
    // Via column `user_id` in products table
    return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
}

// And:
public function products()
{
    // Via column `user_id` in products table
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Product', 'App\Retailer');
}
```

How am I able to unify these two relations into one?

Comment: Is a retailer just a special type of user? Meaning one that just has more details stored that a regular user, or is it something completely different?

Comment: @Bogdan The `Retailer` model is the company. Multiple users can be associated with the same retailer (e.g. all work for that company). Users are associated with retailers by the column `retailer_id` in the `users` table.

Comment: How is the connection from the product to the retailer? Because you said a user has a retailer_id and a product has a user_id. So both relations can be direct on the user, So how does a product belong to a a retailer?

Comment: The product has a `user_id` and a `retailer_id`, the latter is used to relate it to the retailer.

Comment: Does it have to be a direct relation and can be gathered in one query or is it ok to use multiple queries?

Comment: I don't really mind to be honest

Comment: Ok then you don't need a hasManyThrough.

Answer (score 1):

```
// User model
public function products()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
}

public function retailer()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Retailer');
}

// Product model
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}

public function retailer()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Retailer');
}

// Retailer Model
public function products()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
}

public function users()
{
   return $this->hasMany('App\User');
}
```

Usage:

```
// with one user
$user = User::find(1);
$retailerProducts = $user->retailer->products;
foreach( $retailerProducts as $product )
{
    echo $product->id;
}


// When getting multiple users, use eager loading to get all products in one query
$users = User::with('retailer.products')->get();
foreach( $users as $user )
{
    foreach( $user->retailer->products as $product )
    {
        echo $product->id;
    }
}
```